# Measuring the battery voltage while the circuit is under load for under-voltage protection

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, undervoltage

I have built a flashlight composed roughly of a raspberry pico which delivers a PWM signal to a powerful array of 4 parallel multiple-LEDs chips powered via a half-bridge driver and two N-channel MOSFETs.

The battery is a 4-cell LiPo pack, and at 100% duty cycle the LEDs draw up to 16 amps.

I thought it would be smart to include some battery under-voltage protection system, and as this is a learning project I thought I'd just build my own...

It consists of a simple voltage divider connected between battery positive and ground and whose mid-point feeds into one of the ADCs of the raspberry pico and I adjust the voltage it reads in software with a constant multiplier to account for the fact that the internal pico voltage reference can vary slightly from one board to another and thus obtain the correct battery voltage... and I set the PWM's signal duty cycle to zero when the voltage comes below a certain threshold.

Except the voltage reading is only accurate when the duty cycle is zero, because I had totally neglected the fact that my battery's voltage would drop significantly when it's drawing several amps!

So my poor-man under-voltage protection system doesn't work at all.

Besides using a dedicated under-voltage protection circuit, can you think of any options here?

How do these under-voltage protection systems even work internally?

I found a [diagram for an under-voltage protection IC](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/battery-protection-circuit.html#:%7E:text=The%20circuit%20monitors%20the%20voltage,risk%20of%20being%20completely%20discharged.) but I don't understand how this gets around the fact that the battery voltage will drop significantly under load.

Is there any software trick I could use to make my crude voltage monitoring system somehow still useful under load?

Comment: How about a model (Ureal = Umeas - R*I) inside your RPi for your resistive voltage drop to compensate?

Comment: Hmm I'm measuring a significantly lower voltage under load, do you mean rather Ureal = Umeas + R*I? Two issues come to my mind: 1) how do I measure I given that it can be over 10 amps and I don't want do waste too much power with a shunt resistor (I could maybe setup a 0.025 ohm shunt resistor with 4x 0.1 Ohm power resistors in parallel though but that would still waste around 6 watts in the worst case), and 2) what exactly would be R given that LEDs are not ohmic devices?

Comment: Do you know or can approximate the current today? For example measure it with external mean once and map to your duty cycle. Yes, plus sign if you have positive current as discharge.

Comment: yes, I'm measuring with a clamp meter, it's a bit flaky but that could do it, I'll try that, thx for the suggestion!

Comment: If that proves to be a solution for you, let me know and I'll post it as a proper answer so this question can be closed.